# Dojo Grid Template

Tags: dojo, grid

In asp.net the DataGrid supports templates. You can provide your own template and have the grid fill the data in your template.

With Dojo Grid, it seems like I can't make my own template outside of the the rigid simplistic cell style grid that Dojo provides.

Does anyone know a way to use a custom template with Dojo Grid? Specifically, with Dojo you're forced to use a cell that corresponds to a data item. I'm looking to use a table as a template with any styling that I choose (rows,columns,rowspans,colspans, more than one data items in a single cell, etc).

Any clues please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it sounds like everything you want is available by customizing the grid. You can do nesting of cells and even have things like Filtering Selects in rows. Unfortunately the docs on this are not awesome so it takes Googling and trial and error if you want very customized features.

Secondly, because of the OO nature of Dojo you can always use inheritance to create mixes of various widgets. Specifically the _templated class allows you to specify an HTML template for your widget, which themselves can included templated widgets.

If that sounds non-trivial, you're right, which is why I would suggest digging deeper into the Enhanced grid and probably open up the code before trying to write something yourself.

I can tell you that I struggled getting it working correctly, but I have hence been pleasantly surprised by features that I needed that I thought I would need to build myself but were built into the grid.